# how to overlay text on background videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I am trying to use different videos for my website using div tags and I also want to overlay text to display. but whenever I do stuffs and use another video as background in div then it displays only one video in full `<html>` not another.
My code is as follows.

```
<div class="video-overlay"></div>

<video class="sqs-html5-video" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/sp-poster.jpg" autoplay loop><source src="vid/1.mp4" type="video/mp4"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/sp-poster-old-ie.jpg" class="ie8-poster"</video><div class="text-copy"><h1>Fullscreen Video w/overlay</h1></div>
```

Now if I put another background video then it will not display.. only 1st video comes to display.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.container { position:relative; }
.container video {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <video id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="play();">
        <source src="video/Motion.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Content above your video</p>
        <form>
            <p>Content Below Your Video</p>
            <label for="input">Form Input Label</label>
            <input id="input" name="input" value="" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**or**

```
<video loop autoplay muted poster="path/to/screenshot.jpg">
    <source src="path/to/video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="path/to/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CSS for that.

```css
.video-overlay{
 position:absolute;
  z-index:9999999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-overlay">Any Text</div>

<video class="sqs-html5-video" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/sp-poster.jpg" autoplay loop><source src="vid/1.mp4" type="video/mp4"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/sp-poster-old-ie.jpg" class="ie8-poster"</video><div class="text-copy"><h1>Fullscreen Video w/overlay</h1></div>
```

Comment: ok then i want to add another background video after 1st video then what to do?

Comment: You need to be more clear. Add another video where? Bellow the first one? After the first one ends...  Please update your question as we answer it .